# Extracting relevant information from a sentence through web scraper?

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

I am scraping [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs) website. I have the script which scrapes the sentence which contains the relevant information.
Now what i want to do is extract following information from the scraped sentence.

- The name of the company that is hiring
- The location of the company
- The position that the ad is for

Job listings which do not have all three required fields will be discarded.

[image: relevent information highlighted]
This is my script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# scrape the given website
url = "https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs"
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

table = content.find("table", attrs={"class": "itemlist"})

array = []
# now store the required data in an array
for elem in table.findAll('tr', attrs={'class': 'athing'}):
    array.append({'id': elem_id,
                  'listing': elem.find('a',                                
                                       attrs={'class': 'storylink'}).text})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the jobs seem to have the following pattern

```
ZeroCater (YC W11) Is Hiring a Principal Engineer in SF
 ^^^^^             ---------        ^^^^^^        -- ^^
Company                             Position         Location
```

You could split the job title at *is hiring* and *in*.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
r=requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
job_titles=list()
for td in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'title'}):
    job_titles.append(td.text)

split_regex=re.compile('\sis hiring\s|\sin\s', re.IGNORECASE)
job_titles_lists=[split_regex.split(title) for title in job_titles]
valid_jobs=[l for l in job_titles_lists if len(l) ==3]

#print the output
for l in valid_jobs:
    for item,value in zip(['Company','Position','Location'],l):
        print(item+':'+value)
    print('\n')
```

Output

```
Company:Flexport
Position:software engineers
Location:Chicago and San Francisco (flexport.com)


Company:OneSignal
Position:a DevOps Engineer
Location:San Mateo (onesignal.com)

...
```

**Note**

- Not a perfect solution.
- Take permission from the site owner.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something less specific than Bitto's answer because if you just look for the regex of "is hiring" then you'll miss all the ones that are phrased "is looking" or "is seeking".. The general pattern is: [company] is [verb] [position] in [location]. Based on that, you could just look for the indexes of 'is' and 'in' if you split the sentence into a list and then take the values before 'is', between 'is' and 'in', and after 'in'. Like this:

```
def split_str(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    where_is = sentence.index('is')
    where_in = sentence.index('in')
    name_company = ' '.join(sentence[0:where_is])
    position = ' '.join(sentence[where_is+2:where_in])
    location = ' '.join(sentence[where_in+1:len(sentence)])
    ans = (name_company, position, location)
    test = [True if len(list(x)) !=0 else False for x in ans]
    if False in test:
        return ('None', 'None', 'None')
    else:
        return (name_company, position, location)

#not a valid input because it does not have a position      
some_sentence1 = 'Streak CRM for Gmail (YC S11) Is Hiring in Vancouver'

#valid because it has company, position, location
some_sentence = 'Flexport is hiring software engineers in Chicago and San Francisco'

print(split_str(some_sentence))
print(split_str(some_sentence1))
```

I added a checker that would simply determine if a value were missing and then make the entire thing invalid with ('None', 'None', 'None') or return all of the values.

output:

```
('flexport', 'software engineers', 'chicago and san francisco')
('None', 'None', 'None')
```

Just an idea, this will also not be perfect as '[company] is looking to hire [position] in [location]' would give you back (company, 'to hire [position]', location)... you could clean this up by checking out the NLTK module though and using that to filter out the nouns vs else.